# Win Server 2008 DHCP on Virtual Network

Tags: networking, virtualbox, dns, dhcp, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm new to network stuff. I have 2 virtual computers running in VirtualBox: 1 on Win XP and 1 on Win Server 2008. I'm trying to create a DHCP server and DNS server on my server. I know how to add roles but I have some questions:

1. Do I need to have a DNS before a DHCP installed?
2. What type of network should I choose for my virtual machines: private network host or NAT?
3. What is a default gateway?
4. What do I need to do on my Win XP to use my own DHCP server?

I already deactivated the DHCP server of VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

1. You shouldn't have to install them in any order, just get them both installed.  If you want to be careful, install DNS first, then DHCP.
2. I would recommend using an Internal Network, this way your virtual network is completely separated from everything else.
3. The default gateway is the IP address of your gateway.  The gateway would connect your isolated virtual network to other networks (like the Internet).  This is typically a router.  You could add a router to your network, or your Server 2008 machine could act as the gateway (you would probably need to add an additional network interface to the machine in Bridged or NAT mode).
4. You shouldn't have to do anything.  Just make sure its setup to "Obtain IP address automatically."

Comment: So I install my DNS server and I create 2 zone(Direct and Reversed) and then I add my Win XP machines to the host ?

Comment: Ok I sucessfully installed DNs and DHCP server, when I "ipconfig" my Win XP recognize my DNS and has an IP. Now to access to the internet do I need to add a NAT on my server ?

Comment: This may help with that part:  http://blog.pluralsight.com/windows-server-2008-as-a-lan-router-running-rip

Comment: Thanks mate I will look this, I got the feeling that it's gonna be a hard part :D I really appreciated your help, thank you ! :)

Comment: No problem, come back with new questions if you run into any problems.